# Condition of LL(3) grammer

Tags: compilers, parsers

To find out whether a grammar G is LL(1) or not, we test this condition among
other conditions, "If whenever `A -> alpha | beta` are two distinct productions of G, `alpha` and `beta` can't derive string beginning with the same terminal.What should be the corresponding condition for a LL(3) grammar?

Comment: "beginning with the same three terminals".